# AFNetworking Serialization Response Error

Tags: ios

I'm using AFNetworking version 3.0 for handling a POST request.
When I run the code I get an error that says:enter code here

```
2016-01-26 16:48:50.181 Voluntree[3590:1749083] In order to validate a domain name for self signed certificates, you MUST use pinning.
2016-01-26 16:48:50.905 Voluntree[3590:1748745] Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x13deb83d0> { URL: https://voluntree.imrapid.io/signup_by_email } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 4;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Tue, 26 Jan 2016 14:48:50 GMT";
    Server = Cowboy;
    Via = "1.1 vegur";
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://voluntree.imrapid.io/signup_by_email, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<32343634>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain}
```

Comment: Can you post your Objective-C code also so we can see what are the settings in the code?

Comment: As the headers printed you the error, looks like you have a problem with the Content-Type - change it to application/www-x-form-urlencoded

Comment: I just changed the acceptableContentTypes to application/json. Works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the header "Content-Type" value to application/www-x-form-urlencoded and not "text/plain" as it right now.

For application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from values by the equals symbol (=). An example of this would be:

MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo

Comment: For some reason, now when I set the content-type to be 'application/www-x-form-urlencoded' or 'application/json' it tells me: unacceptable content-type: application/json...

Comment: @ItayPincas you should send application/www-x-form-urlencoded in Content-Type